# Си. Функция exit не закрывает стандартные потоки?

Tags: c, функции

Вот часть вывода ltrace для утилиты (cut).

```
ltrace -fw10 cut -f1 <(echo)

[pid 3610] fclose() = 0
    rpl_fclose (ip)
    close_stream (ip)
    
    close_stdout (ip)
    
    __run_exit_handlers (ip)
    exit (ip)
    __libc_start_call_main (ip)
    __libc_start_main (ip)
    _start (ip)
[pid 3610] +++ exited (status 0) +++
```

В данном случае потоки закрывает функция `close_stdout`. Которая была зарегистрирована с помощью `atexit` в теле функции `main` утилиты `cut`. Вопрос: Означает ли это что функция `exit` стандартной библиотеки не закрывает потоки? Если закрывает тогда просьба показать фрагмент кода, где это происходит. Если не закрывает тогда почему в документации `man 3 exit` указано обратное? Трассировка простейшей тестовой программы показывает что закрытие потоков вообще не происходит.

Comment: Если процесс умирает по любой причине, операционная система закрывает все потоки ассоциированные с этим процессом. Нет необходимости в функции `exit` как-то специально об этом заботится. Другой вопрос что происходит с буферами этих потоков. Вот их нужно записать перед смертью. Операционная система об этом заботится не будет. Зато об этом заботится runtime C с помощью механизма atexit/close...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy `man 3 exit` говорит, что записывает буферы stdout/stderr перед выходом, кому верить?

Comment: @andreymal, сохранение буферов можно реализовать через механизм `atexit`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy но зачем, если exit (согласно документации) делает это автоматически без всяких atexit?

Comment: @andreymal, https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/exit.c.html - тут `exit` вызывает `__run_exit_handlers` и больше ничего не делает.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy то есть получается, что man врёт?

Comment: @andreymal, `man` не врёт. `exit` действительно записывает буфера. Но делает он это не сам, а опосредовано через `atexit`. Я думаю что `libc` до передачи управления в `main` вставляет в `atexit` функцию записи буферов.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy опосредованно или как-то ещё — это уже внутренняя деталь реализации, которая нас как конечных пользователей уже не касается, наверное? Если exit всё-таки записывает буфера (как именно — неважно), то тогда в чём смысл существования функции close_stdout?

Comment: @andreymal, https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/closeout.c#L98: "Since close_stdout is commonly registered via 'atexit'...". Это такая делать реализации: `exit` запускает цепочку `atexit`, а там вписана `close_stdout`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вы имеете в виду, что функция close_stdout автоматически регистрируется по умолчанию в любой программе?

Comment: @andreymal, да.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy тогда в чём смысл того, что программа cut [регистрирует её вручную](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cut.c#L470)?

Comment: @andreymal, в цепочке `atexit` может быть много функций. Какая-то из функций может прервать цепочку (есть такой механизм). Так как `close_stdout` помещена в цепочку очень рано, то есть шанс что она не будет вызвана из-за проблем в функциях, помещённых в цепочку позже. Имеем баг - что-то там не записывается. Исправление - поместим `close_stdout` на вершину стека (цепочка `atexit` - стек). Тогда она исполнится вне зависимости от более ранних функций. (Думаю что `close_stdout` так написана, что её можно вызывать много раз без вреда). Это моё предположение, не более.